# what is the covering space of figure eight which is corresponding to commutator subgroup.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $ F$ be the free group on two generators and let $F^{'}$ be its commutator subgroup.
Find a set of free generators for $F^{'}$ by considering the covering space of the graph
$S^{1} \vee S^{1}$ corresponding to $F^{'}$ .

I know that this covering space should be free because any subgroup of free groups is also free.because of commutators I have a feeling that this covering space most be [image]

but I don't know my Idea is right or wrong?please help me with your knowledge,thank you very much.

Edit:there is something that make me  a little confused,for $S^{1} \vee S^{1}$ the universal covering space  $\widetilde{X}$ is [image]

and if we take $\frac{\widetilde{X}}{F^{'}}$, this is abelian covering space of $F$,is it true that $\pi_{1}(\frac{\widetilde{X}}{F^{'}})=F^{'}$?

Comment: It's a theorem that if you have a group $G$ acting properly discontinuously on a simply connected space $Y$, then $\pi_1(Y/G)=G$. See for instance Hatcher, Algebraic Topology, proposition 1.40.

Comment: @MikeMiller If I understood correctly, it also requires freeness on top of proper discontinuity (i.e. g.x = x => g is the neutral element)

Comment: @Evariste Indeed. I guess me from 5 years ago assumed freeness was implicit from the question.